# Amazon SES API...Email address is not verified

Tags: php, amazon-ses

I am facing problems while using Amazon SES API. Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Email address is not verified.

```
Array
(
    [Source] => shobhan@multipliersolutions.in

    [Destination] => Array
                    (
                        [ToAddresses] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => shobhanbabu1595@gmail.com
                                        )

                    )

    [Message] => Array
                (
                    [Subject] => Array
                                (
                                    [Data] => Text only subject
                                    [Charset] => UTF-8
                                )

                    [Body] => Array
                            (
                                [Text] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Data] => Text data of email
                                            [Charset] => UTF-8
                                        )
                                [Html] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Data] => HTML Data of email
                                            [Charset] => UTF-8
                                        )

                            )

                )


)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you need to "verify" the sender address before you can use it to send outgoing mail from that address. This is to prevent spammers from just using Amazon SES to create giant spambots

Basically that means sending a special verification e-mail to your intended sender mailbox, and responding to that e-mail to verify that it is a valid email address/mailbox. That mail account should then be used to handle any bounces, complaints, requests to be removed from mailing lists, etc.

See the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html) for details

Comment: I have verified mail address,But the domain verification is under pending ..What should I do...?